# Get the intersection area of two spherical shells

Tags: geometry, spheres

I have two spherical shells (green and red), given by the following radii and the centers.

```
green inner: g_i
green outer: g_o
green center: (gc_x, gc_y, gc_z)

red inner: r_i
red outer: r_o
red center: (rc_x, rc_y, rc_z)
```

The first illustration shows the problem statement from the **side view**, in the second in 3D, where the area I am interested in, is green filled.

[image: Side view of the problem description]

[image]
Source: *The diluted aqueous solvation of carbohydrates as inferred from molecular dynamics simulations and NMR spectroscopy*, Fig.6

*Background information:* I work with two robots, where the interaction range is defined by the mentioned radii for each robot individually. The calculation is for checking whether their is an intersection of their interaction ranges, which are defined by the area (side plot) in range (g_i, g_o) respectively (r_i, r_o) respectively by the green area (3D plot).

**Question**

I would like to get the mathematical representation of the intersected 3D volume area (described with the orange arrow), where the areas [g_i, g_o] overlaps with [r_i, r_o], which I can use for the mentioned application.

Comment: I'm confused that you seem to have a 3d setup but are asking for a 2d area. Do you mean the volume of the intersection? Or its surface area? Or the area of the intersection of both sphere shells with some plane? If so, which plane? Or are your centers 2d after all? Please clarify.

Comment: I updated my question with an additional picture I found online, which hopefully clarifies the question.

Comment: So you want the area enclosed by the generatrix of this solid of revolution. Or equivalently the area where both shells intersect a plane which contains both centers. It's clearer now, thanks.